# Authentication between two iis web sites

Tags: authentication, iis, .net-core, windows-authentication

I've got two websites on iis website A and webiste B. They are running as identity UserA and UserB both local windows users.
I sent request from website A to website B. I want to authorize is request send by UserA. Can use windows authentication to do that?

Comment: Are they on same server ? If not then you may have nore issues in jumping the auth sec from server to server. Try searching for sso between two websites.

Answer (score 0):

> I sent request from website A to website B.

Could you please tell me how you send the request from website A to B? Using hyperlink or httprequest library?

As far as I know, if you send the request from website A to website B by using httprequest library it will not auto add the user if you don't write special codes to add the username and password.

If you have enable the windows authentication in the website B, you should firstly write the codes to add the user name and password or auth token in web site A when sending request. Then you could get the user name according to the request.

If you have enabled the SSO for windows auth, you could get the username according to the current token.

About how to enable the SSO, you could refer to below article.

https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Networking/Single_Sign_On/SSO_with_IIS_on_Windows.html